# How to make php includes for html pages in web site

Tags: php, html

I'm the first to admit that I'm green when it comes to PHP coding. However many years ago, a colleague gave me a pattern to use for joining PHP with HTML to create web pages. Now, I am looking to revamp the site but I want to know if there is a better way to write it? Currently, I have an index.php page which has a layout similar to this:

```
<?php 

if (! isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['content']) || ! $HTTP_GET_VARS['content']){
  $content="home";
}
else 
  $content=$HTTP_GET_VARS['content'];

//1
 if ($content == "home"){
    $page_title="Page Title";
    $keywords="Keywords found in Meta";
    $desc="Description found in Meta";
    $style="scripts/style.css";
    $popupjs="none";
    $storbutnjs="none";
    $retreatjs="none";
    $rolloverjs="scripts/rolloverjs.js";
    $readform_chkjs="none";
    $logo="req-files/logo.html";
    $sidebar="req-files/sidebar.html";
    $main="home.html";
}

//2
if ($content == "about"){
    $page_title="Page Title";
    $keywords="Keywords found in Meta";
    $desc="Description found in Meta";
    $style="scripts/style.css";
    $popupjs="none";
    $storbutnjs="none";
    $retreatjs="none";
    $rolloverjs="none";
    $readform_chkjs="none";
    $logo="req-files/logo.html";
    $sidebar="req-files/sidebar.html";
    $main="about.html";
}

include ("req-files/head.html");
include ($logo);
include ("req-files/navbar.html");
include ($sidebar);
include ($main);
/*include ("scripts/analytics.js");*/
include ("req-files/footer.html");

?>
```

So, if a person typed `http://yourwebsite.com/?content=about` They would get the whole About page built in the browser with all required meta, header, sidebar, footer, javascript, css, analytics, etc. Each of those required parts are html files, some may have php scripts for some of the $ callouts like Page Title, Keywords, etc.

One of my problems is when my client wants to change the name of one of the '($content == " ")' to something else. First, I can change the variable, but then I have to redirect the old name to the new name so that we don't lose page ranking.

For instance, `http://yourwebsite.com/?content=about` needs to be redirected to `http://yourwebsite.com/?content=about-us`.

Eventually, the client will redirect all or most pages to be more direct, `http://yourwebsite.com/about-us`. It is believed that this will make the rebuild go more smoothly when the site is turned into a WordPress website.

So, is there a better way to write this? Is there a better way to redirect URLs?

Thank you...

Comment: You should have a look the MVC Pattern. It's a better, more robust approach than this.

Answer (score 0):

$HTTP_GET_VARS is deprecated. Please try to learn PHP from the official docs.

To answer your problem, another commonly used system is like this:

File: include.php

```
<?php
function topbanner($title) { ?>
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <header>
  Site name, Logo, etc.
  <header>
<?php }

function footer() { ?>
  <footer>
  &copy;2012. Your company name. Best viewed in Mozilla Firefox.
  </footer>
  </body>
  </html>
<?php }
```

Now, create html pages as you would normally do, but make sure the extensions are .php. In those pages, do this.

```
<?php require_once('include.php'); topbanner("Title of this page"); ?>
<h3>Welcome to this site</h3>
<p>Content content content</p>
<img src="image.jpg" />
<?php footer(); ?>
```

This is for simple pages. If you need more complex setup, follow the style of fork-cms to redirect pages using .htacess. Either way, pages are renamed means they lose indexing. Why do pages need to be renamed often?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Yes, I have been trying to learn PHP but I got a little lost. I think I need a new book too... 

Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php 
so you can include html sites in php (var)

`$page = file-get-contents('myHTMLSite.html');`

and

`str_replace('{header}', $header, $page);`